# Selenium Chromedriver not working in Python, Centos Cpanel Server

Tags: python, linux, selenium, centos, cpanel

I installed selenium and chrome driver.

I then created the below code to run it:

```
 from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
 from selenium import webdriver
 chromedriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
 driver.get(url)
 html = driver.page_source
 driver.quit()
 display.stop()
```

The code yields the following error: "'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"

The path is correct. I have tried some variations of the code but they all yield the same message. My webhost claims you cant install selenium on a centos server that has cpanel. Is this true or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Just put chromedriver.exe in the same directory as your script and just pass "chromedriver" for a test. I'm thinking it's permissions or somehow it's not finding the path.

Comment: What does `which chromedriver` output?

Comment: Even when i put it in the same directory, it still yields the same message: "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
" Any other ideas? can it just not be on a centos/cpanel server?

Answer (score 0):

you might use `OS.environ` and chromeoptions